# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.sun.faces.context.ApplicationMap

Tags: jsf-2, jar, tomcat7

i ve a jsf application which works fine on eclipse with tomcat 7. The problem happened when i packaged it (with mvn package..) and put the .war file in the tomcat webapps directory to deploy it.

in the tomcat console i got :

```
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 2, 2012 12:38:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/jsf_prime_ldap] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 2, 2012 12:38:09 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThread
LocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/jsf_prime_ldap] created a ThreadLocal with key of
type [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$1] (value [com.sun.faces.config.Con
figureListener$1@6972f1]) and a value of type [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureLis
tener.ServletContextAdapter] (value [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$Serv
letContextAdapter@18fee4f]) but failed to remove it when the web application was
stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable
memory leak.
```

for more details about this problem, in the localhost's tomcat log file i have :

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.sun.faces.context.ApplicationMap from class com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext$ServletContextAdapter
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext$ServletContextAdapter.getApplicationMap(InitFacesContext.java:331)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCacheKey.<init>(FactoryFinder.java:850)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.getApplicationFactoryManager(FactoryFinder.java:719)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.access$100(FactoryFinder.java:691)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.setFactory(FactoryFinder.java:373)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:666)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:417)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Nov 2, 2012 12:38:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/sun/faces/context/ApplicationMap
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext$ServletContextAdapter.getApplicationMap(InitFacesContext.java:331)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCacheKey.<init>(FactoryFinder.java:850)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.removeApplicationFactoryManager(FactoryFinder.java:810)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.releaseFactories(FactoryFinder.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

in the tomcat lib directory i have added these jars :
commons-beanutils-1.8.3/
commons-collections-3.2.1/
commons-digester-1.5/
commons-logging-1.1.1/
el-impl-2.2/
jsf-api-2.1.11/
jsf-impl-2.1.11/
jsp-api-2.1/jstl-1.2/
primefaces-3.4.1

The application's pom file :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jsfprimeldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf_prime_ldap</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsf_prime_ldap Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- PrimeFaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSF 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- EL -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1_02</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Tomcat 6 need this <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId> <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0</version> </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>jsf_prime_ldap</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and my web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>jsf_prime_ldap</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

i didn't find any similar problem in google.. i wish to find the solution for this problem here.
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *in the tomcat lib directory i have added these jars : commons-beanutils-1.8.3/ commons-collections-3.2.1/ commons-digester-1.5/ commons-logging-1.1.1/ el-impl-2.2/ jsf-api-2.1.11/ jsf-impl-2.1.11/ jsp-api-2.1/jstl-1.2/ primefaces-3.4.1*

Undo this step. Reinstall Tomcat altogether if you're uncertain. Do not ever touch it unless you really understand what you're doing. This is the cause of the whole problem. The classpath has become a messup and the duplicate JARs/classes are conflicting each other.

Webapp-specific JARs doesn't belong in there. They belong in `/WEB-INF/lib`, *expect* of the EL and JSP JARs; Tomcat has as being a JSP/Servlet/EL container *already* its own implementations for this. You should not put JSP/Servlet/EL libraries of a different container make/version in the classpath at all.

Technically, at least the both JSF JARs, the JSTL JAR and the PrimeFaces JAR should be in `/WEB-INF/lib`. However, as you're using Maven, it should already have taken care about this. You don't need to do anything regard this. So all you need to do is to free Tomcat from illegal JARs/classes.

Comment: i did what u told me BalusC : i reinstall Tomcat and put the .war again and resolved each exception by adding the required jar step by step ( the first exception was : ClassNotFoundException: digester.RuleSet which requires the commons-digester.jar (1.8 version) and this jar have its own dependencies which are the commons-logging-1.1.jar and the commons-beanutils-1.7.0. and i then i got the NoClassDefFoundError:(..)ArrayStack which needs the commons-collections jar (3.2.1 version) and finally got the same this topic's exception : IllegalAccessError: com/sun/faces/context/ApplicationMap.

Comment: to make the application running in eclipse i had to add jsf, the jstl and primefaces jars only (no jsp, el or servlet jars). i m actually using the m2e plugin and have doubt that the reason for the problem was to package the application by the "mvn package "instruction in the console so i tried with "maven install" this time but it was't the solution.

Comment: Where exactly did you add the JARs? Tomcat in its default trim is *already* complete and doesn't need additional JARs. You should drop webapp-specific JARs in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib` or specify them in Maven.

Comment: i added jars in the tomcat lib directory, i don't add them in the /WEB-INF/lib too(should i ??) but just specify them in Maven.

Comment: As answered and commented, you should not add those JARs to Tomcat, but instead to your webapp. Keep off from Tomcat!